# EFFDT in criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I have this criteria in EFFDT stated below:

Course Effective Date <= Term Begin Date

Usually in PS Query, EFFDT as part of criteria is MAX so we get the current EFFDT, but how do we incorporate the criteria above to the MAX EFFDT criteria?.

You can see what i did in my PS Query here, but I am thinking this is wrong and you guys can tell me what I did wrong.

--this is the part they get the recent EFFDT:

```
    WHERE ( A.EFFDT = 
            (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_CRSE_CATALOG A_ED 
            WHERE A.CRSE_ID = A_ED.CRSE_ID 
              AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE)
```

--this is the part where I added the criteria above:

```
    AND 1 = 1 AND ( A.EFFDT <  C.TERM_BEGIN_DT OR  A.EFFDT =  
    C.TERM_BEGIN_DT)
```

overall it looks like this:

```
    WHERE ( A.EFFDT = 
            (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_CRSE_CATALOG A_ED 
            WHERE A.CRSE_ID = A_ED.CRSE_ID 
              AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
    AND 1 = 1 AND ( A.EFFDT <  C.TERM_BEGIN_DT OR  A.EFFDT =  C.TERM_BEGIN_DT)
```

Appreciate the help guys

Answer (score 0):

You want to have the maximum effective date <= Term Begin date so you are getting the most up to date course info at the start of the term.  You do your normal effective dating logic, but instead of using the current date (sysdate), use the TERM_BEGIN_DT.

```
WHERE ( A.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_CRSE_CATALOG A_ED 
        WHERE A.CRSE_ID = A_ED.CRSE_ID 
          AND A_ED.EFFDT <= C.TERM_BEGIN_DT) 
      )
```